# What is the proper configuration to persist edgeAgent storage?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am working on an Azure IoT Edge project. Currently I am going through the [production readiness checklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist). I followed the documentation to [use storage on the host filesystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/iot-edge/how-to-access-host-storage-from-module) for the edgeAgent and edgeHub modules.

When I run `sudo iotedge check` edgeHub is OK but edgeAgent raises a warning:

```
‼ production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
√ production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - OK
```

Here is a snippet from the deployment template:

```
"systemModules": {
  "edgeAgent": {
    "type": "docker",
    "settings": {
      "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
      "createOptions": {
        "HostConfig": {
          "Binds": [
            "/home/pi/iotedge/edgeAgent/storage/:/iotedge/storage/"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "env": {
      "storageFolder": {
        "value": "/iotedge/storage/"
      }
    }
  },
  "edgeHub": {
    "type": "docker",
    "status": "running",
    "restartPolicy": "always",
    "settings": {
      "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
      "createOptions": {
        "HostConfig": {
          "Binds": [
            "/home/pi/iotedge/edgeHub/storage:/iotedge/storage/"
          ],
          "PortBindings": {
            "5671/tcp": [
              {
                "HostPort": "5671"
              }
            ],
            "8883/tcp": [
              {
                "HostPort": "8883"
              }
            ],
            "443/tcp": [
              {
                "HostPort": "443"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "env": {
      "storageFolder": {
        "value": "/iotedge/storage/"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of release 1.0.9, there's an issue where edgeAgent's configuration doesn't update unless its image tag is updated. Two options from your current state:

- Use a specific tag in the image settings (always recommended). E.g. `mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0.9`
- Delete the edgeAgent container on the device: `docker rm -f edgeAgent`. It will get restarted in under 30 secs and the new `storageFolder` env var will be picked up.

Run 'iotedge check' again after the container is update, and this warning should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the same documentation and was able to avoid the production readiness checklist warnings on my Raspberry Pi 3.

1) I have configured the "Binds" as per the documentation [Link module storage to device storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-access-host-storage-from-module#link-module-storage-to-device-storage)

```
"Binds":["/etc/iotedge/storage/:/iotedge/storage/"]
```

2) I have provided the user access on the HostStoragePath, from SSH terminal.

```
sudo chown 1000 /etc/iotedge/storage/
sudo chmod 700 /etc/iotedge/storage/
```

3) Restarted Raspberry Pi 3, to make sure the grant access takes into effect.

- Make sure you have host storage folders available on your edge device.
- Make sure to provide the user full access on those folders.
- Try the deployment with your updated manifest, it should probably work.